# Инструменты для рефакторинга Angular приложения

Tags: angular2, рефакторинг

Подскажите, существуют в природе инструменты, которые могут облегчить рефакторинг приложения?

Например:

- переименовываю я класс и везде меняются импорты
- переименовал я метод и он переименовывается во всех местах, где используется + в html-разметке.
- Переношу я компонент из одного места в другое и автоматически меняются пути в импортах

Вроде, с первым справляется VS CODE, второе тоже частично умеет VS CODE, но не меняет в html, а 3-е через раз.

Comment: с 3м тоже хорошо справляется, для этого должны быть плагины, их в маркете куча. Я не пользовался ни одним из них и не пользуюсь, все мои компоненты small and dumb и не превышают 60-70 строчек кода, шаблон точно такой же маленький, поэтому мне не составляет большого труда просто нажать ctrl+h и изменить имя метода

Comment: @overthesanity ну я ориентируюсь по числу скачиваний+оценка и что-то не наткнулся на что-то топовое для ангуляра. =(

Comment: вопрос зачем оно вам - `переименовал я метод и он переименовывается во всех местах, где используется + в html-разметке`, я никогда не видел чтобы кто-то менял названия методов по несколько раз, к тому же шаблон может быть не в html формате, я даже физически не могу представить себе такой плагин и зачем он нужен кому-то